# Very Stupid Question Regarding .getRange()

Tags: google-apps-script

I am really sorry.. this is probably going to be the dumbest question you have seen in a good long time, if not ever...  LOL    I have been pulling my hair out on this for two hours and for the life of me I can't figure out what I am doing wrong...

This is stupid simple. It is a simple SpreadsheetApp.getRange() using the alternate parameters instead of your the usual "A1" reference. I am sure I am screwing up the syntax, but for the life of me I can't seem to figure out or find what it is that I am doing wrong...

This ties in with a larger project, of course, but for the sake of simplicity, this is what I currently have:

```
function test() {
  var teamSheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  teamSheet.getRange("25,25").activate();
  teamSheet.getCurrentCell().setValue("Stuff");
};
```

All I want it to do there is go to Y25 and put in the word "Stuff". This is eventually going to end up in a loop where both the Row and Column values are increasing with each iteration - hence why I am using the alternate parameters instead of just entering "Y25".

I have tried in single quotes, double quotes, no quotes, square brackets, R[25]C[25], on and on... The error message I am getting is either ***Exception: Range not found*** or ***Exception: The parameters (String,number) don't match the method signature for SpreadsheetApp.Spreadsheet.getRange.***

I appreciate this is a bit of a waste of your time and I am likely making some stupid, silly mistake - but I don't see it and I am loosing my mind on this... Please help!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The script you provide always goes to A25 because the current cell of an active range is always the upper left corner.  It's the same as this one.

```
function test() {
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  ss.getRange("25:25").activate()
  ss.getCurrentCell().setValue("A25");
};
```

I don't understand why you would want to but you could right it like this:

```
function test() {
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  ss.getRange("Y25:25").activate()
  ss.getCurrentCell().setValue("Y25");
};
```

And then it would go to Y25 and put "Y25" there or just as easily

```
function test() {
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  ss.getRange("Y25").activate()
  ss.getCurrentCell().setValue("Stuff");
};
```

If this does not answer your question let me know.  Perhaps you should ask it in the context of how you wish to apply it.

Comment: The reference that TheMaster left may also be worth your time to read

Comment: Thank you, Cooper! Ultimately, I think I have misunderstood what those alternate parameters actually do. I was envisioning it as .getRange("1,2") would be the 1st Row and the 2nd Column, as an alternative to "B2". In the end, what I need is a loop that starts at B113 and captures the value, moves to the next column and does it again, all the way to DB113. Then is does it again for every row from 113 to 132. My intention was an embedded loop with the column "number" increasing with each iteration, but clearly that is not going to work. Think I may be just approaching this all wrong...

Comment: I will start a new question that is a little more in detail of my final goal - I was trying to keep it simple.  :)  Really appreciate the help!!

Comment: The  range in the question was `"25,25"` not `"25:25"`. As the error says it's a invalid range

Comment: When you put the parameters in a1Notation you do not use commas to separate them.  If you wish to get the value at row 25 and column 27 that would be .getRange(25,25).getValue() with no quotes.  "25:25" is  all of row 25 only being bounded on the left and right by the edge of the spreadsheet.  Personally, I have no knowledge what .getRange("25,25") produces.

Comment: I just ran it with a script and it produces an error